# How to get inputbox value in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table that displays data via ajax with values printed by html in table:

```
table.row.add({
 
  'idrefaccion': respuesta['idrefaccion'],
  
  'costo': "<input type='number' min='1' name='iptCosto' id='iptCosto' class='form-control form-control-sm' required>",
  'acciones': "<center>"
                       
 }).draw();
```

On 'costo' cell I show an inputbox to enter a value. Later below I try to get the values of the cells:

```
table.rows().eq(0).each(function(index) {

   var row = table.row(index);

   var data = row.data();

   arr[index] = data['idrefaccion'] + "," + data['costo'];
   formData.append('arr[]', arr[index]);
    });
```

I have tried to get the value using the id of the input but it throws me an "undefined" value

the value of "idrefaccion" shows it well but the one of "cost" shows me the code of the input tag

I hope someone can guide me a little how to solve it.
Cheers!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qReIO.png)

Comment: What does `**` mean before and after `data['costo']`?

Comment: removed, sorry (was bold text)

Comment: The table is a jQuery [DataTable](https://datatables.net)?

Comment: yes, i´m using dataTable

Comment: Although PHP might be the server side language for the page, I’m unclear where it fits into this specific problem?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple), it appears that you should let DataTables handle cell editing rather than inject inputs into cells.  That might break the methods for pulling the data from the table.  It would help if you could provide more detail about the problem as the question is unclear.

Comment: This is not an edition, I´m adding products to the table but the price must be indicated in the input before sending it to the database